# Updating angular object array on ng-click

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Related to a previous post, I am really stuck on user click updating an object array in my angular app. In reality, the user click will force an http get. In the sample code here, I have simplified to a hard coded array. Also, the real app has multiple tabs, I have cut down the code to the crux, which is updating of the object on a click messing up the view. For example, the table in the view loses the selectable column. Other bad stuff happens in real app. I suspect some data binding issue?

```html
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header mdl-layout--fixed-tabs">
 <header class="mdl-layout__header">
  <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
   <a href="#fixed-tab-1" ng-click="activateTab('Assets')"  class="mdl-layout__tab">Assets</a>
   <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <main class="mdl-layout__content">
  <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="fixed-tab-1">
   <div class="page-content">   
    <div class="table-content mdl-grid">    
     <div  class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
      <table id=table1 
       class="table-fullwidth mdl-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--4dp" >
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><span class="table-header">Asset</span></th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in restdata">
         <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric mdl-typography--thin">{{ x.asset }}</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>      
      </table>
     </div>   
    </div> 
   </div>   
  </section>  
 </main>
</div>
```

My simple js is like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('homeApp.protect', []);

app.controller('protectCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
 $scope.tabcount = 0;
 $scope.restdata = [];
 $scope.response = [ {"id":"1","asset":"V-1-A1"},
             {"id":"2","asset":"V-2-A1"},
             {"id":"3","asset":"V-1-A2"},
             {"id":"4","asset":"V-2-A2"}];
  
 // activate tabs entered by user
    $scope.activateTab = function (tabId) {
     $scope.tabcount++;
     console.log("In activate tab " + tabId + " tabcount = " + $scope.tabcount);
  
     // get lists of all assets for all agents
  if (tabId == "Assets")  { 
   angular.copy($scope.response, $scope.restdata);
   console.log($scope.restdata);  
  };
  
    };  
    //Default entry on page load
    $scope.activateTab ("Assets")
}]);
```

On initial load, the selectable check boxes look fine. On subsequent tab clicks, they disappear from rows (appear in header only). I have seen other problem with dynamic data. Thanks.